# Passing Core Data objects from DetailViewController to another View Controller

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2

Is there a way to pass Core Data objects from DetailViewController to another View Controller to allow Editing?

From MasterViewController navigate to DetailViewController:

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let myValue = myValues[indexPath.row]
                let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
                controller.detailItem = myValue
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Then From DetailViewController to EditViewController:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showEdit" {

            let controller =  editViewController
            controller.editItem = detailItem
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true


        }

    }
```

But i get nil on my object

**EDIT**

The edit Item is set like this on EditViewController:

```
var editItem: MyValues? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view.

            self.configureView()
        }
    }
```

and the detailItem is set like this in DetailViewController:

```
var detailItem: MyValues? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view.
            self.configureView()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a property for the edit controller, use what you get from the segue.

I.e. (Assuming you're moving directly to your EditViewController): Replace...

```
let controller =  editViewController
```

...with something like...

```
let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! EditViewController
```

...except you should probably test it rather than using `as!`.

===

Updating with my guess about how this came to be.  (See comments.)

You must have created whatever `editViewController` points to in code someplace, which means it's not the same instance/object that is created for you as part of the segue mechanism. In other words, you had two different `EditViewController` objects and you were not passing data to the one that was going to be putting views on the screen.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to do the trick. However why didn't my code work?

Comment: You must have created whatever `editViewController` points to in code someplace, which means it's not the same instance/object that is created for you as part of the segue mechanism.  In other words, you had two different `EditViewController` objects and you were not passing data to the one that was going to be putting views on the screen.

Comment: thank you for your answer BUT mostly for the explanation! Can I request to add this to your answer for others to consult? Also you are right I had it (editViewController) created as a var inside the my class...